# Getting good control over the number of rows and columns displayed when printing a pandas dataframe in the terminal

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

We are struggling to get proper control of the number of columns and rows printed when we print(dataframe). It is super opaque and seems to be based on some mystery terminal size settings.

We are primarily using VScode on ubuntu. Can anyone explain how this works?

Ta, Andrew

Mods: please note, I have checked over lots of similar questions and have not found any answer which really answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could play with [display options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html) of the `pandas`:

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", 10, "display.max_columns", 5):
    <....>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has display [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html).

Have you tried something like

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 100) # ‘None’ value means unlimited.
```